# How can I implement this design that would turn H2s into a menu?

Tags: html, jquery, css, dom, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm getting bogged down with this one.
The client's CMS spits out their FAQs as sets of divs under H2s. The questions open and close answers, using Bootstrap's accordion menu.

The designer wants the H2s turned into a menu that hides and shows the relevant set of FAQs.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
[image]

Codepen of my attempt:
https://codepen.io/geedix/pen/ExKbWmL - it's working, but is it a smart way to do it?
One function I'm sure is not the best way, because I'm confused by binding, is that I dynamically added classnames with numbers, then I find the number to show and hide the corresponding question group when clicked.

```js
        $("li").click(function () {
        console.log("clicked on " + $(this).attr("class"));
        var myNum = $(this).attr("class").substr(1, 2);
        $("li").removeClass("currentBatch");
        $(this).addClass("currentBatch");

        var myGroup = "q" + myNum;
        $(".row")
          .not("." + myGroup)
          .hide();
        $("." + myGroup).show();
      });
```

Comment: you also need to add code in the question you have been working on.

Comment: ok, is a code excerpt required when you post a question? I thought I could just discuss the concept.

Comment: You will need to iterate through all the cards and find the headings of type h2. after that look for the closest according and bind it's onclick with that according.

Comment: Sorry, but you are supposed to provide a [reprex]. SO is specifically for solving programming problem, not a discussion board. However, a basic approach would be: `.text-block { display: none } .menu-item:focus + .text-block { display: block } /* + adjacent selector, ~ sibling may work too */` where `.menu-item` is an `<a>` (or any other element that can receive focus). Don't immediately think *accordion*, just *focus or no focus* (no bootstrap required), the rest is just layout design. *Checkbox trick* would work too, but involves much more work.

Comment: Ok I made a codepen of what I'm trying to do. I probably did it the hard way. It's basically working. Now I need to implement it on the actual site. https://codepen.io/geedix/pen/ExKbWmL